# Use the fundamental theorem of calculus to prove that the integral $f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If $f(0)=f(1)=0$ Prove that $$\int_0^1 e^x(f(x)+f'(x))dx=0$$

Use the linearity principal:

$$\int_0^1f(x)e^x+e^xf'(x)dx=0 \to \int_0^1 e^xf(x)+\int_0^1 e^xf'(x)dx$$

Now I am not sure how to proceed because this requires integration by parts but there is no polynomial or natural log. Initially I just plugged in the end points and got zero with out integrating but thats not right for the first integral

Comment: Guess the anti-derivative!!

Comment: Use the product rule

Comment: You can do integration by parts. $u=f(x)$ and $dv=e^x$ for the first integral. Swap for the next.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$
\int_{0}^1 e^xf(x)\,\mathrm d x=e^xf(x)\Big|_0^1-\int_0^1 e^xf'(x)\,\mathrm d x
$$